# Near Api to fetch all the transactions of an address till date or at any particular blockheight

Tags: nearprotocol

I found a api "view_account" method using which i can fetch the balance of an address at a particular blockheight. Is there any Api or a way where i pass an address and it provides all the supporting transactions for the balance.

Answer (score 2):

NEAR Protocol nodes do not store the data in that way, and it would be unrealistic to do so for all the use-cases out there, so the solution is to index the network block by block. There is an official [Indexer Framework](https://github.com/near/nearcore/tree/master/chain/indexer) based on the official NEAR node implementation (nearcore), or you can use JSON RPC and build it yourself. There is an official [Indexer for Explorer](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer), which stores the data in PostgreSQL database ([see the schema in the README](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#database-structure)), and we have a [public shared read-only replica](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer#shared-public-access) available for everyone out there to play with.

Flux implemented an indexer for their needs (also based on Indexer Framework): [flux-capacitor](https://github.com/fluxprotocol/flux-capacitor)

Answer (score 0):

I, too, encountered challenges in obtaining transactions at one point in time.

To acquire the transactions, I utilized their public Postgres SQL database, which can be found at the following link: [indexer-for-explorer](https://docs.near.org/tools/indexer-for-explorer)

However, this solution is not suitable for production purposes, as the database was often non-functional (at least a year ago) and sometimes experienced excessively long timeouts (I can provide the query if needed).

Ultimately, I settled on using [CryptoMation](https://www.cryptomation.com/blog/getting_transaction_in_near), a service comparable to Scan services but with support for the Near Network.